# Why am I unable to access OpenPGP keys on Seahorse and access encrypted files?

Tags: encryption, gnupg, seahorse, openpgp

I am unable to access my OpenPGP keys on Seahorse. I tried to create a new key but the key never appeared (though it did prompt me for details). After trying to create a new keyring none of the keys were showing. I also reinstalled Seahorse.

When I do `gpg --list-keys` all the keys are listed and they also appear in seahorse when I `sudo seahorse`. However I am unable to access the files through the context menu (it says I dont have the decryption keys). When I attempt to import the keys from `/home/####/.gnupg/pubring.gpg` permission is denied.

Any suggestions on how to access these files?

Also I need to transfer some of these locked files onto another Ubuntu machine. If I create a new key with the same private key (I mean the passphrase I normally use to open the files on this machine) will I be able to open them?

My `~/.gnupg` directory:

```
 drwx------ 3 bill bill 4096 Sep 13 23:28 .
 drwxr-xr-x 59 bill bill 4096 Sep 13 23:25 ..
 -rw------- 1 bill bill 9398 Jul 7 00:14 gpg.conf
 drwx------ 2 bill bill 4096 Sep 13 22:31 private-keys-v1.d
 -rw------- 1 root root 334311 Sep 13 22:17 pubring.gpg
 -rw------- 1 root root 334311 Sep 13 22:17 pubring.gpg~
 -rw------- 1 bill bill 600 Sep 13 22:42 random_seed
 -rw------- 1 root root 7645 Sep 13 22:17 secring.gpg
 -rw------- 1 bill bill 1520 Sep 13 22:17 trustdb.gpg
```

Comment: What user are you running `gpg` as? Run `ls -la ~/.gnupg` to check the permissions.

Comment: total 696
drwx------  3 bill bill   4096 Sep 13 23:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 59 bill bill   4096 Sep 13 23:25 ..
-rw-------  1 bill bill   9398 Jul  7 00:14 gpg.conf
drwx------  2 bill bill   4096 Sep 13 22:31 private-keys-v1.d
-rw-------  1 root root 334311 Sep 13 22:17 pubring.gpg
-rw-------  1 root root 334311 Sep 13 22:17 pubring.gpg~
-rw-------  1 bill bill    600 Sep 13 22:42 random_seed
-rw-------  1 root root   7645 Sep 13 22:17 secring.gpg
-rw-------  1 bill bill   1520 Sep 13 22:17 trustdb.gpg

Comment: Please don't put such follow-up content into comments (and in this case, format as code), but edit your question instead. In the comments, its barely readable.

Comment: so sorry for that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you ran GnuPG as root at some time, and it created your keyring files with root being the owner:

```
 -rw------- 1 root root 334311 Sep 13 22:17 pubring.gpg
 -rw------- 1 root root 334311 Sep 13 22:17 pubring.gpg~
 -rw------- 1 root root 7645 Sep 13 22:17 secring.gpg
```

Run `sudo chown -r bill:bill /home/bill/.gnupg` (user folder guessed from user name) to repair the file ownership.

Comment: I used sudo "chown -R bill:bill /home/bill/.gnupg" which worked fine. Thanks a lot